# BroadcastReceiver in Service not working

Tags: android

This is my service file:

```
public class SMSCounterService extends Service {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SMSCounterService: Constructor");
        super.onCreate();
        dbActivities = new DBActivities(this);
        dbActivities.open();    // Create or open the existing DB if already created

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        dbActivities.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT")) {
                smsCount++;
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SMSCounterService: smsCount=" +smsCount);
                long dbInsertReturn = dbActivities.insertIntoDB(smsCount);
            }
        }
    };
```

I can see the log "SMSCounterService: Constructor". So the onCreate() method is called. But when I send an SMS, the BroadcastReceiver is not able to identify it.

Comment: Are the correct permissions set in your manifest? I think it is the RECEIVE_SMS permission  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: what makes you think that there is any intent when an sms is sent? And why do you think that the intent is "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"? I think your receiver is okay. Make a simple app with only one button and on click of that button just send an intent android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT and see if your receiver can catch it well. If it does, then I was right and there is no any intent like this when an SMS is sent.

Comment: What @alex.veprik wrote is completely correct - afaik, there isn't an SMS_SENT broadcast, just SMS_RECEIVED.

Comment: @alex and Jens: I have checked some tutorials and it looks like SMS_SENT broadcast is present (although not sure about the authenticity of it!). One reference tutorial: http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1969&sid=d214adbe78c1ae826800abb944f2da41

Comment: @webgenius: Perhaps you are right. But I just ran a grep through the entire android sources (Ice Cream) and couldn't find a match. When I was digging in to this a year ago I've come to abandoning this approach and decided to go with ContentObserver objects to listen for SMS/MMS provider updates.

Comment: @alex: Thanks for the update. Looks like ContentObserver is the way to go now for the time being. Wonder why Android does not provide SMS_SENT broadcast. I've seen that most of the modem vendors provide unsolicited response to Android framework about the result of SMS send. It is just a matter of broadcasting this result in the framework code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no intent like android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT. 
I did "grep" through Ice Cream Sandwich and couldn't find it.

Go with ContentObserver approach. Register your observer to listen to updates messaging provider. 
(Decided to register it as an answer, who knows maybe somebody will accept it ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did some research on my own and realized that ContentObserver is the only way forward for the time being. Will give it a try today and hopefully everything will go well :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the required permission(s) in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

For sending:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

For receiving:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: @Waqas: Adding permissions won't help since I'm not sending nor receiving SMS in my app. I'm only interested in the use-case when some other messaging app sends an SMS.

Comment: i dont think you can be aware of events when other apps send sms